# Convert a number and accept any decimal separator

Tags: c#, formatting

I have a double number `0,401780062641746`

I want to format it to `0.40178006`

I'm using this code:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00000000%}", dNum);
```

But the result is `40.17800626`

I want to be able to type either `.` or `,` for decimal separator. So I'm using

```
NumberStyles.Any
```

Example:

```
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dNum);
```

but apparently that's a problem and now I can't convert the number the way I want.
Any ideas?

Comment: did you try this -> `double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dNum);`

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Yes but this way won't allow me to use numbers like 0,123 but only 0.123

Comment: @user3473957: Do you need to be able to cope with grouping separators as well? For example, `3,456` might mean "between 3 and 4" or "between 3000 and 4000".

Comment: @JonSkeet No, I don't need this, only decimal separator is needed. So in your example the number would be between 3 and 4.

Comment: I would call TryParse twice, once with a culture that uses `.` as the separator and once with a culture that uses `,`. Omit NumberStyles.AllowThousands to prevent ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *only* need to cope with decimal points, so you don't need to handle grouping separators, the simplest option would be to just replace any commas with dots:

```
string input = ...;
input = input.Replace(',', '.');
double value;
if (double.TryParse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    // Use value
}
else
{
    // Handle invalid input
}
```

Note that this will *only* cope with `.` and `,` as decimal separators, and won't perform any other culture-specific parsing.

Comment: Also about format: `string.Format("{0:0.00000000}", dNum);`, remove % symbol.

Comment: @user3449857 What's the difference?

Comment: % multiplies your value by 100. Used for percents.